# Stub Element Is Not Effective In The Ready Function

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component-tester

With Polymer 1.* and WCT, when testing my element `<sp-veteran></sp-veteran>` I am not able to stub out the methods `._getSpComboBox()` and `._getItems()` in the `ready` function. I get `Error thrown outside of test function: this._getSpComboBox(...)._getItems is not a function`.

Since it is in the ready function, I need to use the WCT api `stub` instead of `sinon.stub` since the later requires me to grab the element which I can not do before `fixture()`.

Any suggestions?

original code:

```
  _getSpComboBox: function() {
    return Polymer.dom(this.$.veteran.root).querySelector('sp-combo-box');
  },

  ready: function() {
    if (this.editMode) {
      this._getSpComboBox()._getItems();
    }
    this.$.veteranNoAjax.read();
    this._setStyle();
  }
```

test:

```
<test-fixture id="sp-veteran">
  <template>
    <h2>edit veteran in edit mode</h2>
    <sp-app>
      <sp-toast></sp-toast>
      <sp-veteran edit-mode></sp-veteran>
    </sp-app>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

  before(() => {
      replace('sp-app').with('fake-sp-app');

      stub('sp-ajax', {read: ()=> entitiesMock});
      const _getItems = ()=> entitiesMock;
      stub('sp-veteran', {_getSpComboBox: ()=> _getItems});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately testing ready in Polymer1 is kind of a pain, or at least I haven't found an easy way that doesn't have odd side-effects.  Calling the ready method after you've attached your stubs/spies is always an option but as I mentioned it can cause some odd issues.  This was alleviated in Polymer2 as ready is called by the first call of connectedCallback for your element, so you can create the element then bind your spies and manually add to trigger it, just don't forget to remove after.

In the case of DOM manipulation in a Polymer element, you should be using the attached lifecycle instead, this will solve your issue as I mentioned above for testing, but it also saves you a weird potential usage case in the future.  Since ready only runs once for an instance of an element, any logic in your ready statement won't get re-run if that element is re-used later, instead if you put the logic in your attached lifecycle if that element is removed from the DOM then added again later in another location it will rerun it's logic to fetch it's new children.

Comment: Using `fixture()` which invokes the `attached` method. How could I query the element to attach the spies before `fixture()` is invoked? As far I can tell, `fixture()` needs to be stamped first so I can query the dom to attach the stub.

Comment: If you're using fixture you cannot rely on spies/stubs, you can only observe the effects of your code (when it comes to testing attached) if you need to use spies and stubs you'll have to use document.createElement, you can then add your spies and manually attach to the DOM which will trigger the lifecycle event.  On a side note, if you use the code approach instead of the template approach the fixture method takes 2 parameters, the first is the element type you are creating and the second is the model, the model is meant to set the default properties but you may be able to replace methods?